# Zepto Velocity.js Typescript definitions

Tags: typescript, zepto, velocity.js

I have tried looking for type definitions for velocity the only one i could find is on tsd `tsd install velocity-animate' but does not support velocity using Zepto. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Zepto and JQuery are mostly type compatible. You can just use the definition for JQuery and only load `zepto.js` at runtime.

Comment: i have no issues at runtime it's just for the linting errors before running it